# How do I create a lambda expression of type Expression.Lambda<Action<Controller>>? dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, expression-trees

I am trying to create a lambda expression of type `Expression.Lambda<Action<Controller>>` dynamically.

For instance: `x => x.Index()`

```
var body = ???
Expression<Action<Controller>> action = Expression.Lambda<Action<Controller>>(body);
```

I have the controller type (Type) and the controller action (MemberInfo).

Comment: You mean the actual controller is a type derived from `Controller`? So you actually want something like `x => ((ConcreteController)x).Index()`?

Comment: The Controller class is belonging to ASP.NET MVC. All controllers are derived from this class. I also could change my question into: How do I create a lambda expression of type Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would do it using [`Expression.Call()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb349020.aspx). Something like:

```
Expression<Action<T>> CreateCallExpression<T>(MethodInfo method)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    return Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(
        Expression.Call(parameter, method), parameter);
}
```

Comment: Do you know how can I add method parameters? I tried Expression.Paramter and Expression.Variable with no success.

Comment: That depends, where do you get the value for that parameter? Should it be constant, or from parameter of the expression, or something else?

Comment: It should be constant default values (default(T) if possible.

Comment: In that case, something like `Expression.Call(parameter, method, Expression.Default(typeof(ParameterType)))` should work for a method with one parameter.